# Apache Ignite - simple Python example

Tags: python, ignite

I started Apache Ignite node on my local Mac and tried to run Python script to see if it can connect:

```
import pylibmc
client = pylibmc.Client (["127.0.0.1:11211"], binary=True)
client.set("key", "val")
```

Got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    client.set("key", "val")
pylibmc.UnknownReadFailure: error 7 from memcached_set: (0x7fd26cc3d8d0) UNKNOWN READ FAILURE,  host: 127.0.0.1:11211 -> libmemcached/response.cc:828
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Or if you have simpler example with step by step to run Apache Ignite with Python, please let me know. (I tried few examples on line and none so far worked)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To connect to Ignite using a Python client for Memcached, you need to
>   download Ignite and -
>
> 1. Start Ignite cluster with cache configured. For example:
>
> Shell  bin/ignite.sh examples/config/example-cache.xml
>   2. Connect to Ignite using Memcached client, via binary protocol.
>
> Python  import pylibmc
>
> client = pylibmc.Client (["127.0.0.1:11211"], binary=True)
>
> client.set("key", "val")
>
> print "Value for 'key': %s"%client.get("key")

from: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/memcached-support#python

Looks like you didn't pass proper config to ignite:

> bin/ignite.sh examples/config/example-cache.xml

Comment: Thanks, just used example-cache.xml and it worked. Do you have more examples with Python (e.g. compute, sql etc.). thanks.

Comment: only c# and java can work with distributed computation.

Comment: Also Ignite supports ODBC: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/quering-data so you can query it via odbc lib for python. Unfortunately I don't have an examples for this.

Comment: To my knowledge, Ignite C++ can also work with distributed compute.